# How to make references between two existing classes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, class, reference

Rails newbie here; so I have three classes - user, article, comment - where,

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :articles
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article
end
```

Now I'm wanting the comments to be user specific i.e. each comment will be linked to a user (just how every article is linked to a user). How do I go about doing that apart from adding has_many and belongs_to in user.rb & comment.rb? I hope I made myself clear.

Answer (score 0):

Add similar relations to `User` and `Comment`. So a comment will have an `user_id` as well as an `article_id`.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :articles
  has_many :comments
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article
  belongs_to :user
end
```

You will have to write a migration after alerting your models to add an `user_id` field to your `comments` table.

```
rails g migration AddUserRefToComments user:references
```

Then run `rake db:migrate`. Hope that helps.

Comment: I've already done that. Nothing else is required in the controllers?

Comment: No, nothing to do in controllers. But while creating a new comment, you need to save the current user's id in that comment.

Comment: Thanks! I'm probably being thick, but I'm having trouble to save the current user's id in the comment. I'm trying `@article.current_user.comments.create(comment_params)` in the `create` method in `CommentsController`, where `@article = Article.find(params[:article_id])` but it's returning an error

Comment: undefined method `current_user' for #<Article:0x007fb2ef7569b8>

Comment: Okay, right. So there is no current user for `@article`. You should do `@article.user.comments...`